# Lighttpd url rewrite with php mvc

Tags: php, regex, lighttpd

I wish to reroute all requests on `root/cvideo/...` to `root/cvideo/index.php`, the problem comes on js and css which also get routed, this is the best I can do...

```
url.rewrite-once = ( "/(js|jpg|css|)/$"=>"$0",
                     "^/cvideo([^?])*$"=>"/cvideo/index.php" )
```

My regex seems regit but it result in a 404 error whenever I access a js or css file, other parts works fine. Help? Please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex pattern is a bit wrong:

```
url.rewrite-once = (
    "^.*\.(js|jpg|css)/?$" => "$0",
    "^/cvideo" => "/cvideo/index.php"
);
```

Do note that, I'm unaware of how lighttpd handles `$0` groups, which is why I've added the `.*` in pattern.

Comment: Thanks this works well, now i can continue coding, but what does /? before terminating a string does? @hjpotter92  in-case i meet the need regex again

Comment: @EliyaKonzo It makes the `/` character optional. You can entirely remove `/?` from the pattern.